# Why does RowsAdded return not all rows?

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, datagridview

There are 3 rows in Datagridview. I see that after runnig application.

But when I use `RowsAdded` event, it shows only `0,1` in console. It should be `0,1,2`, why?

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
   Console.WriteLine(e.RowIndex);
}
```

I use `dataGridView1_RowsAdded` to modify cell data. It works for all rows excepting last row:

[image]

You can see that previous two rows were modified(date). The last was not

Minimal example:

```
private void dataGridView1_RowsAdded(object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("ok");

    string birthday = dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
        .Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn42"].Value.ToString();
    DateTime dt = DateTime
        .ParseExact(birthday, "dd/mm/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    birthday = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex]
        .Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn42"].Value = birthday;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Datagridview` property `AllowUserToAddRows` set to true, The last row is for insertion and As `@Fruchtzwerg` mentioned

Comment: It is false, really

Comment: Yes, You can try it.

Comment: It is not reason. Property `AllowUserToAddRows` is already in false

Comment: See my question

Comment: I tried it and it's as you said, but what you want to do exactly,
you can handle it after databinding use dataGridView1_BindingContextChanged instead

Comment: Do you mean to replace event on `dataGridView1_BindingContextChanged`?

Comment: private void dataGridView1_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
string birthday = dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn42"].Value.ToString();
    DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(birthday, "dd/mm/yyyy",                                  CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

   birthday = dt.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells["dataGridViewTextBoxColumn42"].Value = birthday;
            }}

Comment: Method `BindingContextChanged` does not has `e.RowIndex`

Comment: Also this methos does not chnage cells, because it returns `dataGridView1.Rows.Count` zero rows

Answer (score 1):

The behaviour is documented at the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowsaddedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> The RowsAdded event occurs when rows are added to a DataGridView control. When the user adds a new row using the row for new records, the RowIndex value in the handler for this event is equal to the index of the new location of the row for new records, which is one greater than the row just added. When you add rows programmatically, however, the RowIndex value is the index of the first row added.

`RowIndex`:

> Gets the index of the first added row.

Note that the last row is to insert new data. This means this row is not added to source until the user inserted valid data. At this point a new row to insert data will pop up.

Comment: Have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/specify-default-values-for-new-rows-in-the-datagrid

Comment: I have not found nothing by link

Comment: Look please question again, I added new data

Comment: Sorry, but without a minimal working example we can't help you. It's absolutely not clear how you are modifying the format by printing something in the console.

Comment: Okay, I will share now